# Smart pointer that lazily recreates its resource

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, object-lifetime

I have a `ServiceProvider` class which contains a couple of pointers to different services, like that:

```
class ServiceProvider()
{
    Service3* GetService3();

public:
    void Process(Object* o);
    void Shrink();

private:
    TAutoSpawningPtr<Service1> service1;
    TAutoSpawningPtr<Service2> service2;

    Service3* service3;
}
```

Note that `TAutoSpawningPtr` is a theoretical smart pointer сlass I'm looking for, and service3 is declared as an ordinary pointer to explicitly show the behaviour I needed.
The body of `Process()`:

```
void ServiceProvider::Process(Object* o)
{
    service1->Process(o);
    service2->Process(o);
    GetService3()->Process(o);
}
```

The body of `GetService3()`:

```
void ServiceProvider::GetService3()
{
    if(!service3)
    {
       service3 = new Service3();
    }

    return service3;
}
```

As you can see, an instance of `Service3` is being created lazily and it don't exist until it needed.

`Shrink()` method is being called periodically to delete all internal services. Like this:

```
void ServiceProvider::Shrink()
{
    service1.Release(); // delete its internal Service1 pointer if it exists.
    service2.Release(); // delete its internal Service2 pointer if it exists.

    if (service3)
    {
        // delete its internal Service3 pointer if it exists.
        delete service3;
        service3 = nullptr;
    }
}
```

**What do I need:** I want `TAutoSpawningPtr<>` to be a smart pointer class, which *automatically* creates its class instance by calling the default construcror once I dereference the pointer using an overloaded `operator->`. An inner resource posessed by the pointer had to be deleted once called the `Release()` method (and, of course, it had to be recreated when I need it again).

**Why do I need this?**

1. To automatically control presence/absence of an object.
2. To prevent nullptrs when derefenecing pointers directly (like `this->service3->Process(o)`) instead of indirect `GetService3()`.
3. To release unused services without explicit checks.

**The question is:** Does the standard (or any third-party) library have an auto pointer class which will satisfy my needs? And if not, would you kindly to bring me some code examples that shows behavior I need. Thanks.

Comment: Is the service a shared resource or is there only a single owner? If there is only a single owner, the proxy solution from Curious is fine. Otherwise you may need some wrapper around shared or weak pointers.

Comment: @pschill good observation!  updated my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution here would be to just call a function that initializes the two if they are uninitialized or are not pointing to anything.

But if you really want to, you can create a simple proxy pointer class that does this for you.  For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Something {
public:
    Something() {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
    void do_something() {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
};

template <typename Type,
          template <typename...> class Ptr = std::unique_ptr>
class AutoAllocatingPtr {
public:
    Type* operator->() {
        if (!this->ptr) {
            this->ptr = Ptr<Type>{new Type{}};
        }
        return this->ptr.get();
    }

    void release() {
        this->ptr.reset();
    }

private:
    Ptr<Type> ptr;
};

int main() {
    // default unique ownership with std::unique_ptr
    auto ptr = AutoAllocatingPtr<Something>{};
    ptr->do_something();
    ptr.release();
    ptr->do_something();

    // if you want shared ownership
    auto s_ptr = AutoAllocatingPtr<Something, std::shared_ptr>{};
    s_ptr->do_something();
    s_ptr.release();
    s_ptr->do_something();
}
```

**Note** Note the code in the end and how you can use that to switch the type of ownership semantics that the pointer exhibits.

Comment: The unique_ptr solution has a pitfall: If you move from `AutoAllocatingPtr` with `Ptr=unique_ptr` and reuse the moved-from object, a second instance will be spawned. I think this is against the purpose of a unique_ptr. Do you have an idea how this behavior can be avoided?

Comment: @pschill i feel like that's what OP would want in the case right?  Because essentially that would be releasing the memory that was there in the old instance.

Comment: @pschill however a simple solution to that case would be to just check if the type of `Ptr` is `unique_ptr` and then throw an exception (`logic_error` or a variant of that) when `operator->` is used on a moved from `AutoAllocatingPtr`.  The check would be optimized to be a no-op at runtime in C++14 and will 100% be a no-op at runtime with `if constexpr` in C++17

Comment: @pschill although it seems like clang has a bug regarding this! https://wandbox.org/permlink/1rbEA3aQ9FW3rX2E

Comment: I am not sure that this is the AutoAllocatingPtr expects as desired by OP. From the name Service / ServiceProvider and since OP mentions smart pointers, I would expect that a service type cannot exist multiple times. But I guess only OP can tell us the exact requirements.

Comment: @pschill The only difference can be in the `release()` method from what I make from OP's question, but that would be a small change I feel